# How do I prevent the no 'get' attribute error when validating a form?

Tags: python, django

I have a class in views.py and when I run the code I get the following error:

> object has no attribute 'get'

Can anyone help?

```
class currencyconvertGBP():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        login_id = '###############'
        api_key = '####-####-####-####'
        environment = currencycloud.Config.ENV_DEMO
        client = currencycloud.Client(login_id, api_key, environment)

    def GBPconvert(request):

        if request.method == "POST":
            form = Convert_Form_GBP(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                sell_currency = form.cleaned_data.get('sell_currency')
                buy_currency = form.cleaned_data.get('buy_currency')
                amount = form.cleaned_data.get('amount')                    
                form = Convert_Form_GBP()
                form.save()
                print(sell_currency)
                print(buy_currency)
                print(amount)
```

try:
                    rate = client.rates.detailed(buy_currency='EUR', sell_currency='GBP', fixed_side='buy', amount=amount)
                    print("To buy {0} {1} you will need to sell {2} {3}. This quote will be valid until {4}".format(rate.client_buy_amount,

```
                                                                                                        rate.client_buy_currency,

                                                                                                        rate.client_sell_amount,

                                                                                                        rate.client_sell_currency,

                                                                                                        rate.settlement_cut_off_time))
            except ApiError as e:
                print("Detail Quote encountered an error: {0} (HTTP code {1})".format(e.code, e.status_code))

            return render(request, 'main/conversion.html', {'content': [("To buy {0} {1} you will need to sell {2} {3}. This quote will be valid until {4}".format(rate.client_buy_amount, rate.client_buy_currency, rate.client_sell_amount, rate.client_sell_currency, rate.settlement_cut_off_time))]})
        #return render(request, 'main/form.html', context={'currencyconvertform': form})

    else:
        form = Convert_Form_GBP()           
        return render(request, 'main/form.html', context={'currencyconvertform': form})
```

The URL pattern is:
path("account/currencyconvertGBP/", views.currencyconvertGBP, name="currencyconvertGBP"),

After the API reponse is returned I thought I could get the objects from the first class and resubmit to the API again using the second class:

class currencyconvertedGBP(currencyconvertGBP):
    def **init**(self, *args, **kwargs):
        login_id = '############'
        api_key = '##############'
        environment = currencycloud.Config.ENV_DEMO
        client = currencycloud.Client(login_id, api_key, environment)

```
def GBPconverted(request):

    try:
        conversion = client.conversions.create(buy_currency='EUR', sell_currency='GBP', amount=amount, fixed_side='buy', reason='Top up Euros balance', term_agreement='true')
        print("Conversion Id {0} for {1} {2} created successfully".format(conversion.id, conversion.client_buy_amount, conversion.buy_currency))        


    except ApiError as e:
        print("Conversion encountered an error: {0} (HTTP code {1})".format(e.code, e.status_code))
    return redirect("/convert_success")
```

Comment: What's `form.cleaned_data`?

Comment: can you print `form.cleaned_data` after the is_valid() and send us the output?

Comment: elif request.method != "POST":
            form = Convert_Form_GBP()

Comment: That isn't how you write class-based views in Django. Either write a regular function outside of the `currencyconvertGBP` class, or subclass Django's `View`. When you ask a question about an error on Stack Overflow, please include the full traceback, because it will show exactly where the error occured.

Comment: also reverse the order of this form = Convert_Form_GBP()
                 form.save()

Comment: I am trying to submit data captured on a form to an API. Should the method be 'get' or 'post'?

Comment: Traceback:

File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py" in __call__
  93.             response = self.process_response(request, response)

File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py" in process_response
  26.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /account/currencyconvertGBP/
Exception Value: 'currencyconvertGBP' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Please don't post errors or code in the comments. [Edit] your question. Please show your URL pattern as well.

Comment: After the form is submitted, the API does return a response. The user is then given the option to accept the response. Therefore, the objects created by the first form then need to be resubmitted to the API a second time to accept the response. I thought I could create two classes and the second class would inherit from the first. What you see in the code above is the first class.

Comment: How would I write a subclass for this?

Comment: You can't use Python classes to store state between requests like that. Unless you are familiar with class-based-views in Django, I suggest you write function-based views. You can either re-submit the data in the second request, or store it somewhere like the database or session. Be careful that the user doesn't change the data between requests if you store it in the cookie or get them to resubmit the data.